# Strange behavior of setMarginStart with supportsRTL false in Manifest

Tags: android, layout, right-to-left

Consider the following snippets:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
   android:text="StrangerThings"/>
```

Java side,

```
TextView tv =findViewById(R.id.tv);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMarginStart(0);
```

with supportsRTL flag set to true in Android Manifest, above code produces text with 0 margin as expected. However, with supportsRTL false, setMarginStart has no effect.

Moreover, with SupportsRTL false, no matter how you set left margin (in xml or programatically using setMargins), once you set left margin, setMarginStart has no effect on it.

Is it the intended android behavior or a bug? Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** - `android:supportsRtl="false"` puts the app into "RTL compatibility mode", which causes `startMargin` to be ignored in any case where `leftMargin` is defined. Removing the `android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"` attribute allows `startMargin` to take effect.

---

Inside the `MarginLayoutParams` class, two different fields track "left" margin and "start" margin (these have very creative names: `leftMargin` and `startMargin`). Similarly, two different fields track "right" margin and "end" margin.

The class pretty much does all of its work using "left" and "right" margins; it just goes through a process that resolves the "start" and "end" values (based on layout direction) to "left" or "right". Here is the source code for that method:

```
    private void doResolveMargins() {
        if ((mMarginFlags & RTL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE_MASK) == RTL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE_MASK) {
            // if left or right margins are not defined and if we have some start or end margin
            // defined then use those start and end margins.
            if ((mMarginFlags & LEFT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK) == LEFT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK
                    && startMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) {
                leftMargin = startMargin;
            }
            if ((mMarginFlags & RIGHT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK) == RIGHT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK
                    && endMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) {
                rightMargin = endMargin;
            }
        } else {
            // We have some relative margins (either the start one or the end one or both). So use
            // them and override what has been defined for left and right margins. If either start
            // or end margin is not defined, just set it to default "0".
            switch(mMarginFlags & LAYOUT_DIRECTION_MASK) {
                case View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL:
                    leftMargin = (endMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) ?
                            endMargin : DEFAULT_MARGIN_RESOLVED;
                    rightMargin = (startMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) ?
                            startMargin : DEFAULT_MARGIN_RESOLVED;
                    break;
                case View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR:
                default:
                    leftMargin = (startMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) ?
                            startMargin : DEFAULT_MARGIN_RESOLVED;
                    rightMargin = (endMargin > DEFAULT_MARGIN_RELATIVE) ?
                            endMargin : DEFAULT_MARGIN_RESOLVED;
                    break;
            }
        }
        mMarginFlags &= ~NEED_RESOLUTION_MASK;
    }
```

When the manifest is set with `android:supportsRtl="false"`, we go into the first branch of the top `if` statement. So now the question is just whether or not the left margin is "undefined"... and we know that it is **not**, since the view tag specified `android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"`. As such, the value passed to `setMarginStart()` is ignored.